# Wordpress - Jetpack infinite scroll "post-load" event not firing

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I recently started playing around with the infinite scroll feature of the wordpress jetpack plugin.  It seems to work ok, but I'm trying to integrate with Masonry, so I need to use the post-load event that's supposed to fire when Jetpack loads more posts.

But I can't seem to catch that event.

I have a very minimal set up (with a supported, default theme - twentyfourteen) and I added this small script to footer.php to try and catch the event:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.body.addEventListener("post-load", function() {
        alert('posts loaded');
      });
    </script>
```

But I never get my alert even though the new posts are loaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: congrats on your tumbleweed badge! :p

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and I was looking for an answer too. The reason it doesn't work is because the infinity.js script used by Jetpack fires the `'post-load'` event using the jQuery `.trigger()`.

`.trigger()` [is not a native event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144202) so it doesn't get picked up using addEventListener.

Use:

```
jQuery(document.body).on("post-load", function(e) {
    // your code
})
```