# document.addEventListener vs. $(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, ecmascript-6

I somehow found a bit strange behavior of adding eventlisteners to document. While adding listeners to HTMLElements works fine adding a listener to document doesn't work. But the strange thing is, that using jQuery makes it work.

So can someone explain, why this two functions are not doing the exact same thing?

```
["customEvent1", "customEvent2"].forEach(
    (event: string) => {
        document.addEventListener(event, () => this.eventHandler());
    });

$(document).on("customEvent1 customEvent2", () => this.eventHandler());
```

EDIT:
Well it seams that there is some misunderstanding about the environment.

1. The function is surrounded by a class
2. I'm using TypeScript/ES6
3. the EventHandler is a class method
4. the custom event is triggered with `$(document).trigger("customEvent1")`;

Comment: One is jQuery(_less code_) and other is core JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean with `[...]adding a listener to document doesn't work[...]` . I this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx6get1r/) you can see that it does work.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal How is that a dupe?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I don't see that this is a duplicate. The OP claims that there is a difference between`addEventListener` and jQuery's `.on`. Your linked question is about `addEventListener`  vs the `on[eventname]`  property.

Comment: How are you triggering the custom events?

Comment: most likely the context of `this` is different ...

Comment: The custom event is triggered with `$(document).trigger("customEvent2");`

Comment: Well there you go.... Either do it with jQuery or pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery does not create a native event if you use `$(document).trigger("customEvent2");` ([jquery src/event/trigger.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/52e24471c89b80e6208b4987bb76994e64c1e489/src/event/trigger.js)), it only emulates the native event handling.

So if you register an event handler using `document.addEventListener` then your cannot use `$(document).trigger(` for those events.

But if you create and dispatch an event using native code:

```
var event = new Event('customEvent1');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then you can catch it with both `document.addEventListener` and jQuery's `.on`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know your arrow function is wrong. You can do it this way, because the descructuring of `(event: string)` is wrong here. And because `() => eventHandler()` is a bit redundant you can just pass in the `handler`.

```js
function eventHandler() {
    console.log("custom event");
}

["customEvent1", "customEvent2"].forEach(
    event => document.addEventListener(event, eventHandler)
);

var event1 = new Event('customEvent1');
document.dispatchEvent(event1);

var event2 = new Event('customEvent2');
document.dispatchEvent(event2);
```

And keep in mind, you can't trigger events, registered with vanilla js, with jQuery. jQuery only create `event-like` callbacks and not real events. So you have to use `trigger` then.

```
// ok
document.addEventListener('customEvent1', eventHandler);
var event1 = new Event('customEvent1');
document.dispatchEvent(event1);

// ok
$(document).on("customEvent2", eventHandler);
$(document).trigger("customEvent2");

// ok
$(document).on("customEvent3", eventHandler);
var event3 = new Event('customEvent3');
document.dispatchEvent(event3);

// not okay
document.addEventListener('customEvent4', eventHandler);
$(document).trigger("customEvent4");
```

Comment: You can trigger a jQuery event handler with vanilla JS. Take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/gx5xhhr1/2/ . So the statement " if you register it with jQuery, you can only trigger it with jQuery" is not true.

Comment: You're right. A bit wrong written. That was the reason for my `not okay` example. I hope my text is more clear now. Thanks @Anton

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NOT in the way you attach event handlers. Both `addEventListener` and the `on` method are fine. However the problem might be either in the `forEach` or in the lambdas which changes the scope of `this` to something you do not expect. To ensure you refer to the correct object, change the code like this:

```
var self = this;
["customEvent1", "customEvent2"].forEach(
    (event: string) => {
        document.addEventListener(event, () => self.eventHandler());
    });

$(document).on("customEvent1 customEvent2", () => self.eventHandler());
```

The `this` keyword is a bit tricky as it is contextual